# How to solve this FILTER query for user LOGOUT

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-filters

I have this code for filtering cache pages but facing some problems while compiling:

```
package bean.log.filter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

public class LoginFilter implements Filter
    {
    @Override

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
        {  
        try
        {


        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res; 
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); 
        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("userHash") == null)
            { 
            response.sendRedirect("/scape/applicationservices/fileshare/vm/login/login.jsp"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1. 
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            }
            else
                { 
                chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
                }
            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

After compiling the same I get following error:

```
D:\programs\MyPackage\bean\log\filter>javac LoginFilter.java
LoginFilter.java:14: bean.log.filter.LoginFilter is not abstract and does not ov
erride abstract method destroy() in javax.servlet.Filter
public class LoginFilter implements Filter
       ^
1 error
```

So I made changes in my code as below then it compiled but I am not getting desired result .The changes I made are:
I put `@Override` and `implements Filter` in comment and added `public void init` and `public void destroy` method

```
package bean.log.filter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

public class LoginFilter // implements Filter
    {
    //@Override
        public void init( ) 
        {   
        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
        {  
        try
        {


        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res; 
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); 
        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("userHash") == null)
            { 
            response.sendRedirect("/timescape/applicationservices/fileshare/vm/login/login.jsp"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1. 
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            }
            else
                { 
                chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
                }
            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void destroy( ) 
        {   
        }

}
```

How to cofigure filter in web.xml

I configured it like below

```
<web-app>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>     
        <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>     
        <filter-class>bean.log.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class> 
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping>     
        <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>     
        <url-pattern>/scape/applicationservices/fileshare/vm/apps/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

I want this filter to restrict user to go back after LOGOUT to previous cache pages which are in my `apps` directory so I use that `url-pattern`.
how to achieve this filter to be worked.

Answer (score 1):

A Java EE filter has to implement the interface you mentioned above: [javax.servlet.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). Your problem doesn't lie in the `Filter` itself but in your Java usage. In this language when some non-abstract class implements the interface it or its parent has to implement **all** the declared methods. It means, that when the interface declares methods `init()`, `doFilter()` and `destroy()` then your class has to implement all of them even when the implementation should be empty. It means that you have to combine your both solutions:

1. uncomment `implements Filter`
2. let uncommented methods `init()` and `destroy()`
3. possibly uncomment `@Override` if you are using Java 6 or later

After that your filter should be fine, at least it should be executed when the web container processes some page matching URL specified in your `web.xml` mapping.

Anyway I guess that the logout URL is not usually so complicated so I would expect the mapping URL to be something like `/logout`. As I already mentioned the filter is executed **only** with pages matching the URL.